# How would you properly translate "of the Gods" into Latin?

Tags: english-to-latin-translation, vocabulary, etymology

I am trying to translate the phrase "of the gods" into Latin. Google translate says it would be *deorum*, however I am skeptical of the accuracy of Google translate, other sources say it is correct, then others say its not even a word in Latin. Any help would be much appreciated.

Also if *deorum* is correct what is the etymology of the word.

Comment: What are the genders of those gods? All male, all female, or mixed?

Comment: I'm sorry for the late response, what would the difference be in each of the three cases?

Comment: I wrote up an answer to address that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is correct. "Deorum" is the genitive plural of "Deus" meaning "God". The stem of "Deus" is "Deo", and the gentive plural suffix is "-rum".

Comment: Thank you for the help, I appricate it

Answer (score 1):

The answer depends on the genders of the gods.
Latin has three grammatical genders — masculine, feminine, and neuter — and some words have different forms for different genders.

If the group of gods is all male or a mixed group of men and women, then you need the masculine form ***deorum***.

If the group of gods is all female (goddesses rather than gods if you will), then you need the feminine form ***dearum***.

There are several possible words for a god(dess), including *deus/dea, divus/diva, numen, caeles, caelestis*.
To get an idea of their differences and nuances, I recommend taking a look at any of the [many online Latin dictionaries](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/867/79) and asking a question on this site if more clarification is needed.
The most standard choice would indeed be *deus/dea* (whose plural genitives I gave above), but depending on context you might want something else.

Answer (score 1):

One other way is simply ***deum***, which you can see in formulaic phrases like *deum hominumque*.

You can also find the archaic spellings ***divom***/***divum***, such as in Vergil's *ast ego, quae divom incedo regina*.